# How do i google login in react native expo project? (with firebase)

Tags: firebase, react-native, oauth, expo, google-signin

I am trying to login google in my expo project, but although I did everything stated in the documentation, I get the following error;

**Error:**
expo-google-sign-in is not supported in the Expo Client because a custom URL scheme is required at build time. Please refer to the docs for usage outside of Expo [www.npmjs.com/package/expo-google-sign-in](http://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-google-sign-in)

**Doc:**
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/google-sign-in/

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3bZa.jpg)

**AuthStack**

```
import * as GoogleSignIn from 'expo-google-sign-in';

export default function AuthStack() {
const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = React.useState(null)
let routeName;

React.useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then(value => {
        if (value == null) {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true');
            setIsFirstLaunch(true)
        }
        else {
            setIsFirstLaunch(false)
        }
    });

    try {
        GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
            clientId: 'my-clientid',
        });
    } catch ({ message }) {
        alert('GoogleSignIn.initAsync(): ' + message);
    }

}, [])
```

**AuthProvider**

```
import * as GoogleSignIn from 'expo-google-sign-in';

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

const _syncUserWithStateAsync = async () => {
    user = await GoogleSignIn.signInSilentlyAsync();
    user(true)
};

const signOutAsync = async () => {
    await GoogleSignIn.signOutAsync();
    user(null)
};

const signInAsync = async () => {
    try {
        await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync();
        const { type, user } = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
        if (type === 'success') {
            _syncUserWithStateAsync();
        }
    } catch ({ message }) {
        alert('Error: ' + message);
    }
};

 
 return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
            user,
            setUser,
     
            googleLogin: async () => {
                if (user) {
                    signOutAsync();
                } else {
                    signInAsync();
                }
            }
       
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
```

}

**Button**

```
const { login, googleLogin } = useContext(AuthContext)

                <SocialButton
                    buttonTitle="Sign In with Google"
                    btnType="google"
                    color="#de4d41"
                    backgroundColor="#f5e7ea"
                    onPress={() => googleLogin()}
                />
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to says this: "expo-google-sign-in provides native Google authentication for standalone Expo apps or bare React Native apps." If you're using the Expo Client, you're out of luck unless you eject.

Comment: yes, i used google auth, i solved thx for help

Comment: @developerysn But google auth page says its deprecated. Can you provide the link?